# Distorted plane as image

Tags: image

After importing as plane image. This happens.
[image]

Original png on left. How can i avoid this?

Comment: Do you get the same result in rendered view and/or the rendered image? I don't think the textured view handles alpha transparency all that well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha values range from 0-255.  Your image editing program is hiding pixels with very low values such as 1-3 into that background checkerboard pattern.  Blender is expecting 0 for complete transparency.

Open image in GIMP, use the magic wand tool to select transparent area, then click <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

*File* >> *Export As...* and give it a new name, or *Overwrite PNG* if you are satisfied with results.