# transparency issue in blender render with shading?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, transparency

Unsure how to fix this problem, just a generic fire in a fireplace, but the transparency isn't working correctly for some reason.

I'm in Blender Render. Not sure exactly what to search for to find the answer to this so I'm just asking.

Thanks, and I'm sorry if this is a repost of a previously asked question.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99864/distorted-plane-as-image

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts/42026#42026

Comment: not a duplicate of either, the top link the transparency wasn't working on the imported image, the second one was done in cycles rendering. i figured it out though. I had to deselect traceable under material>options though neither link answered the question they did help me find the answer. thank you

Answer (score 1):

when using a transparency in Blender Render ensure that in the material tab , under options that the traceable box is unchecked so as to not cast a shadow on the transparent portion of the texture.
[image]
[image]